# I cannot change Page Wrapper with ann way

Tags: magento2, page, header.panel

I will start with a strange problem that I cannot find its solution for a week.

In my template, there are a lot of kind of headers. In the most of them there is a problem.

They have a line in top in which there is the text "Free Shipping On Orders Over $59".

I try to find the phtml file of header an I find this part:

```
<div class="panel wrapper">
<div class="header-panel <?php echo ($full_header_width == 1 ? 'full_header_width' : 'container')?>">
    <div class="topbar-container">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top.contact"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("currency"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("store_language"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem come from the top.contact.

[image]

Is there anyone that can help me changing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the issue exactly ? do you want to remove that text from header part on all pages ? or just on specific page or want tot change the text ? could you update your question so we know what sort of help do you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete / remove that header text, then go to that template and comment out `$this->getChildHtml("top.contact");` line like below :

```
<div class="panel wrapper">
    <div class="header-panel <?php echo ($full_header_width == 1 ? 'full_header_width' : 'container')?>">
    <div class="topbar-container">
        <!-- Comment this line -->
        <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml("top.contact"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("currency"); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("store_language"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2 :**

If you want to change text then you should search for "top.contact" in your **default.xml** file (`Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`) and see which template or cms block is being called.

From there you will be able to find appropriate resource and change the text.